# SubViews not getting removed

Tags: iphone, uiview, subview

Can someone tell me why this code isn't removing the subview that's being animated? The views are stacking up and the second time I dismiss the view, it won't animate and there are now two instances of subView with tag 99. It wasn't released the first time.

```
for (UIView *subview in [self.smallView subviews]) {
    NSLog(@"view:%@",subview);
    if (subview.tag == 99) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                         animations:^{
                             subview.alpha = 0;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             subview.alpha = 0;
                             [subview removeFromSuperview];
                         }];
    }
}
```

Here's how I add the subview, viewVC is a ViewController Subclass and smallView is where I add my map and is the container for all the views.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomViewController *viewVC;

viewVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VIEWVC"];
viewVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 371);

viewVC.view.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
viewVC.view.tag = 99;
viewVC.view.alpha = 0;
[self.smallView addSubview:viewVC.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                 animations:^{
                     viewVC.view.alpha = 1;

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     viewVC.view.alpha = 1;

                 }];
```

Comment: Could you please clarify why you are checking for the value of subview.tag to be 99?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are doing what you want to do with this code.  Can you build a little method that iterates the subviews counts the subviews with tag==99 and prints the count?  Call it outside the loop, then call it in the completion block.  My guess is that the count will be correct after the removeFromSuperview.  I think you're re-adding the view someplace else.

Comment: you don't need that completion block after you add the view and bring up the alpha, but that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you're removing an object from the array you're iterating through, which will cause problems.  Try this:

```
NSArray *subviews = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.smallView subviews]];
for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
    NSLog(@"view:%@",subview);
    if (subview.tag == 99) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                         animations:^{
                             subview.alpha = 0;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             subview.alpha = 0;
                             [subview removeFromSuperview];
                         }];
    }
}
```

This way, you are no longer removing an object from the array you are iterating through.

Comment: @sch, you're right, I'm off target here.  I've modified my code based on your catch.  Eric, please refer to sch's answer.

Comment: And you are sure that the if statement is getting called? Here, I'm in the middle of something so I'll try to get back to you after it's done (which will be a few hours).

Comment: if is getting called and the above code produces the same result of stacked views

Comment: The problem was that a notification to call the above code was getting added twice. So the views were not stacking up, but the code to remove was getting called every time I added a new subview. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify why you are checking for the value of subview.tag to be 99? Is it at all possible that the code in the if statement isn't getting called at all? Throw in some NSLog calls, and see if your code within that if statement is even executing. If it is, then you should check out the methods that you are invoking within the if statement and make sure that they are all okay.